# Quickest way to implement matrix calculation JAVA Android

Tags: java, matrix, runtime

I have a speech enhancement algorithm with a lot of matrix calculations it runs about 30 sec's on my PC  but when I ran it on my phones it took about 5 minutes. I implemented all matrices and vector calculation  with lists and double for loops  I was wounding if there is a quicker way for example would ejml help in this case? what library would be the most efficient one when run time is most important?

Comment: Are these static or dynamic ? I also think bottle neck is somewhere else.May be few lines of code would help.

Comment: Both data structures and algorithms are important in your case. Did you research about dynamic programming applied to matrices ?

Comment: This question is quite vague, so it will be quite difficult to provide specific help. Are you multiplying the matrices? Are you finding determinants? Are you adding and subtracting matrices? What is happening in the for loops? How many items are in the matrices?

Comment: Sorry about being vague I am doing mostly basic mathimatical oparations which is matrix multiplying adding and matrix element multiplying (.* oparatior in Matlab),and all matrix sizes are known pre run.